# Algebraic properties of the algebra of continuous functions on a manifold.

Tags: manifolds, fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

> Does the algebra of continuous
>   functions from a compact manifold to
>   $\mathbb{C}$ satisfy any specific
>   algebraic property?

I'm not sure what kind of algebraic property I expect, but I feel that because of the Gel'fand transform, it may not be unreasonable to expect something. We can drop the compactness condition if we switch to continuous functions to $\mathbb{C}$ that vanish at infinity.

I'm really hoping for some necessary and sufficient condition, but if anybody knows of any sort of condition, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5344/algebraic-description-of-compact-smooth-manifolds

Comment: @Steven: so far, on MO only $C^{\infty}(M)$ has been discussed, not $C(M)$, as in my question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21168/how-to-classify-the-algebras-cm

Comment: @Eric: so you're asking for a condition of a commutative $C^*$-algebra (in their language) whose spectrum is a manifold?

Comment: @Martin: yes, that's right. 

Comment: @Steven and Martin: thanks for the references. I thought I remembered similar questions, but I couldn't find them for the life of me. I feel like it may be a bit simpler to get some condition on the C^*-algebra of continuous functions to C rather than the R-algebra of smooth functions to R simply because of the Gel'fand transform, but this may be a misplaced suspicion.

Comment: While your question is quite natural I think you might profit from working out just what kinds of algebra you want to exclude or include with your condition(s). For instance, C(M) will not be an integral domain - it has lots of proper zero divisors. However, the class of "algebras which are not integral domains" includes loads of algebras that look nothing like C(M).

Comment: Also, the way your question is worded seems a bit odd to me. "Does the algebra of continuous functions from a compact manifold to C satisfy any specific algebraic property?" well, it's unital, but presumably that's not the kind of answer you were looking for.

Comment: @Yemon: of course, we look for very special properties ... (or even a characterization). 

Comment: @Martin: well, I thought so, but I think it would be useful for the original poster to try and formulate a more precise version - I know this is not always easy, but following a Polya-type philosophy it really helps in these situations. (Besides, what is a formal definition of "purely algebraic characterization"? some kind of statement about full and faithful functors perhaps?)

Comment: @Yemon: I phrased the question vaguely somewhat on purpose, for the chance that there was some cool and fairly well-known result I was not aware of. Now that it seems like there is not, I agree with you that it would be good to rephrase it and ask with a more specific intent. 

Comment: @Eric: fair enough. I was meaning to think more seriously about this question today but other chores intervened. Certainly, if a commutative algebra is isomorphic to C(X) for some compact Hff space X (let alone a manifold) then it has to have trivial Jacobson radical, i.e. it is (Jacobson) semisimple.

Comment: David Speyer once wrote a blog post suggesting that the existence of partitions of unity should be thought of as an analogue of the Nullstellensatz, so maybe that will lead you somewhere. 

Comment: I don't see how partitions of unity would be used to distinguish a compact manifold from any other compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: @Qiachu: Thanks for the suggestion. I took a look at that blog entry, and it was really interesting. It seems like there should be some sort of connection between these partitions of unity and my question, but so far I haven't come up with anything relevant. I also agree with Jonas' comment that we'll need something more than just the existence of partitions of unity, since we have them in any compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: @Yemon: That's a good observation, I had forgotten about that. Thanks. I think this may give me a better starting point for investigating my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a reference for a necessary property that might be called algebraic.

Browder [proved a theorem](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183524331) relating the number of generators of a complex commutative Banach algebra to the Čech cohomology with complex coefficients of the maximal ideal space, and as a corollary concluded that if $M$ is a compact orientable $n$-dimensional manifold, then $C(M)$ cannot be generated as a Banach algebra by fewer than $n+1$ elements. The paper is very short, but for an even shorter summary [here's the MR review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=130580).

---

Just some comments, added later:

One obtains the compact Hausdorff space $X$ (up to homeomorphism) from $C(X)$ by considering the maximal ideal space of $C(X)$ with Gelfand topology, but clearly you want something less tautological than "the maximal ideal space is a manifold."  A small step in this direction would be to try to formulate the topological properties of $X$ in terms of the closed ideals of $C(X)$.  As alluded to in Qiaochu's comment, there is an analogue of Nullstellensatz: each closed ideal in $C(X)$ consists of all functions vanishing on a (uniquely determined) closed subset of $X$.  So for example, the locally Euclidean property could be reformulated for a commutative C*-algebra $A$ as follows: There is an $n$ such that for every maximal ideal $M$ of $A$ there is a closed ideal $I$ of $A$ such that $I$ is not contained in $M$ and $I$ is $*$-isomorphic to $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  Second countability of the maximal ideal space [is equivalent to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space#Properties) $A$ being separable in the norm topology; that's not algebraic, but might be considered more intrinsic to the C*-algebra.

But this only leads to another, more specific question: Is there a useful or interesting (C*-)algebraic characterization of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$?`

Comment: If I remember rightly from having skimmed over that paper *en passant* a few years ago, an important point is that one gets $n$ rather than $2n$? Or have I misremembered?

Comment: Browder emphasizes that if we were talking about real-valued generators then the corresponding result would be trivial, but for some compact Hausdorff spaces fewer generators are required in the complex case.  So the point seems to be that the lower bound of $n+1$ had previously not been known, even in the case of $S^2$ as Browder (and Rudin in the review) point out.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean about $2n$, but I might just be slow.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure you're not being slow and I'm just going prematurely senile;) What you describe in your comment sounds familiar -- I just remembered that there was something to do with posssibly, *a priori*, having different answers in the real and complex cases.

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks for the paper, it was interesting. While it fits my requirements of an algebraic property (well, C^*-algebraic, but we have no other choice in that), I think I'm going to wait and see what other interesting things crop up :). 

Comment: @Eric: For what it's worth, it's better than C*-algebraic; it's Banach algebraic.  E.g., $C(S^1)$ is singly generated as a C*-algebra, but requires 2 generators as a Banach algebra.  I was tentative about posting, hence the "might be called algebraic" and the community wiki, but I'm glad you find it interesting.

Comment: This is not meant as a criticism, but I've noticed on this (and on the related posts about $C^\infty(M)$) that the crux of the matter is what we mean by a "characterization". Here a balance would need to be struck between the most formal, precise definition (almost getting a bit type-theoretical) and an informal one which admits nice answers. The spectral triple formalism is, in my view, more towards the latter end of the scale; but it's also perhaps proven to be the most fruitful POV.

Comment: Yemon, thanks for the comment. I don't know what characterization should mean here, and of course Eric was very up front about not knowing himself what he's looking for. Taken too literally, it would be easy to say (as I mentioned above) that "the maximal ideal space is a manifold" is an "algebraic characterization".  I agree that spectral triples seem more fruitful, but doesn't that theory always concern smooth manifold structure?  What would be an analogue for just topological manifolds? [This comment replaced a 2-day-old one with overlapping content.]

Comment: Okay, so after I had some time on my hands, I was finally able to play around with this question again after Jonas' revised answer. In short, I didn't find anything else. Of course, if our manifold is compact, then referring to Jonas' answer, we can always find finitely many such ideals which are *-isomorphic to $C_0(R^n)$. Then our entire algebra will be the sum of these ideals. I couldn't find much else other than that. And of course Jonas is right in that it brings up another question about interesting properties of $C_0(R^n)$. 

Comment: @Yemon: I'm afraid I don't know anything about spectral triples(other than what wikipedia tells me), but thanks for the suggestion nevertheless. I'm sorry my question was not very precise and therefore frustrating. I guess some properties don't translate well. Thanks again to everybody for all the suggestions!